# Spotfire Weighted Median value

Tags: python, r, spotfire, median, weighted

Is there any function which returns weighted Median value?

Input 2 columns like
weight = [100,210,30,50]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

and maybe function like WeightedMedian(w = weight, v = values)

or can you help me to construct code for that, Data-->Data Function Properties --> Expression Functions --> New.

or formula in Custom Expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighted median is just the first value for which the cumsum of the weights divided by the total sum of all weights exceeds 0.5.

```
WeightedMedian <- function(w, v) {
  
  # in case when v is not sorted 
  i <- order(v)
  v <- v[i]
  w <- w[i]
  
  v[which(cumsum(w) / sum(w) > 0.5)[1]]
  
}

WeightedMedian(w =  c(100, 210, 30, 50), v = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by weighted median you mean the median of the value column, where the weights represent the number of times the distinct value occurs,
you could create an Expression Function that takes the [value] and [weight] and returns the weighted median (a column with a single value repeated
in all rows).

Function type: Column function, Return type: Real, Category: Statistical functions.

One option would be to use the R library DescTools. You need to install it first (top menu > TERR Tools > Package Management >
Load the CRAN repository, then type DescTools into Available packages, select the desired package and Install)

Then the script would be:

```
library(DescTools)
wmedian = DescTools::Median(input1,weights=input2)
output=rep(wmedian,length(input1))
```

Alternatively, without adding any library, you could expand the initial [value] column by the [weight] column, and calculate the plain median:

```
expanded_value=rep(input1,times=input2)
wmedian=median(expanded_value)
output=rep(wmedian,length(input1))
```

Call this new function WeightedMedian and define the calculated column as:

```
WeightedMedian([value],[weight])
```